# Server side pagination of AngularJS ng-grid

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement this server side pagination example of ng-grid mentioned here http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ . Unfortunately, I do not quite understand the code.

Here is my situation:
1. Say I have a page which has 2 text boxes and a button. I would like to post the values of these two text boxes to a web service on ng-click of the button. Returned json should be displayed as grid. But the code in the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/50vJrs?p=preview

```
 $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var data;
        if (searchText) {
            var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
            $http.get('largeLoad.json').success(function (largeLoad) {      
                data = largeLoad.filter(function(item) {
                    return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                });
                $scope.setPagingData(data,page,pageSize);
            });            
        } else {
            $http.get('largeLoad.json').success(function (largeLoad) {
                $scope.setPagingData(largeLoad,page,pageSize);
            });
        }
    }, 100);
};
```

will render the grid on page load (which I do not want). What I dont understand is how to associate the $scope.getPagedDataAsync function with a ng-click?

2. The html code doesnt have any textbox for searching through the grid even though in the controller they have $scope.filterOptions. How is the search happening the in plunker code?

Wish there was more documentation on the site.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the plunker, the function quoted in your question is immediately invoked:

```
$scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);
```

Does commenting out that line have the desired effect?

As for the filter, it's probably there as a convenience so you can add a filter text field yourself.  It is defined in an object so you can use a custom directive or ng-include block.

Comment: My apologies but I do not understand why you are asking to comment that our? Say I have $scope.StudentName and $scope.Grade text boxes and ng-click="getStudentGrid()". So how can I make sure getStudentGrid calls this getPagedDataAsync?

Comment: Just comment out the line where it's called. At the minute you have `function foo () { ... }` and then on the next line `foo()`. The second part is why the grid is populated on page load, the script effectively clicks for you one time.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for being so lame. I understand that I need to comment the line you mentioned. But I am still wondering how to $scope.getPagedDataAsync with the two parameters page size and current page from the getStudent() function?